# What would be the best possible way to support multiple boolean combinations for a test in pytest?

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, testing, pytest

So basically, what I am trying to do is, to generate all possible combinations of three boolean flags and later on do some operations on the basis of those combinations. Is there a way, I can do this using parameterization in pytest?

For example, my code could look something like this:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("is_flag_1,is_flag_2,is_flag_3", [(True, False), (True, False), (True, False)])
def test_something(self, is_flag_1, is_flag_2, is_flag_3):
        print(is_flag_1, is_flag_2, is_flag_3)
```

And this can then generate 8 possible combinations like:

1. False, False, False
2. False, False, True
3. False, True, False so on and so forth till True, True, True

So instead of writing 8 different test cases, I want to do this through single test, leveraging pytest. If there is some other way other than parameterization, even that would work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can just parametrize the flags separately:

```py
import pytest

@pytest.mark.parametrize("is_flag_1", [True, False])
@pytest.mark.parametrize("is_flag_2", [True, False])
@pytest.mark.parametrize("is_flag_3", [True, False])
def test_something(is_flag_1, is_flag_2, is_flag_3):
    print(is_flag_1, is_flag_2, is_flag_3)
```

`python -m pytest -vv` results in something like:

```
================================================= test session starts =================================================
...
collected 8 items

parametrize_bool.py::test_something[True-True-True] PASSED                                                    [ 12%]
parametrize_bool.py::test_something[True-True-False] PASSED                                                   [ 25%]
parametrize_bool.py::test_something[True-False-True] PASSED                                                   [ 37%]
parametrize_bool.py::test_something[True-False-False] PASSED                                                  [ 50%]
parametrize_bool.py::test_something[False-True-True] PASSED                                                   [ 62%]
parametrize_bool.py::test_something[False-True-False] PASSED                                                  [ 75%]
parametrize_bool.py::test_something[False-False-True] PASSED                                                  [ 87%]
parametrize_bool.py::test_something[False-False-False] PASSED                                                 [100%]

================================================== 8 passed in 0.35s ==================================================
```